# Java AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes() returns empty array in android

Tags: java, audio, decode, wav, pcm

### The goal: Play wav sound with the help of AudioinputStream and AudioSystem in Java on android

```
private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;
private File soundFile;
private AudioInputStream audioStream;
private AudioFormat audioFormat;
private SourceDataLine sourceLine;

public void playSound(){

    AudioFileFormat.Type[] types=AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes();

    System.out.println("supported formats: ");
    for(AudioFileFormat.Type t1: types){
       System.out.println(t1.getExtension());
    } 
  
    try {
        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("res/raw/" + "tobu_wav" + ".wav"));


    audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();

    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
    try {
        sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        sourceLine.open(audioFormat);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    sourceLine.start();

    int nBytesRead = 0;
    byte[] abData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while (nBytesRead != -1) {
        try {
            nBytesRead = audioStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int nBytesWritten = sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
        }
    }

    sourceLine.drain();
    sourceLine.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

The code works fine.
The probem is after this line:
System.out.println("supported formats: ");

Android: types={}
PC (Windows): types={"wav,"au","aif"}
Why? - How can I add these supported File types to work on android as well?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you're on Android why not use [its media API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out.

AudioTrack is the solution on Android devices.